# How do I write a Perl script to filter out digital pictures that have been doctored?

Tags: regex, perl, photoshop

Last night before going to bed, I browsed through the Scalar Data section of Learning Perl again and came across the following sentence:

> the ability to have any character in a string means you can create, scan, and manipulate raw binary data as strings.

An idea immediately hit me that I could actually let Perl scan the pictures that I have stored on my hard disk to check if they contain the string Adobe. It seems by doing so, I can tell which of them have been photoshopped. So I tried to implement the idea and came up with the following code:

```
#!perl
use autodie;
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    local $/="\n\n";
    my $dir = 'f:/TestPix/';
    my @pix = glob "$dir/*";

    foreach my $file (@pix) {
        open  my $pic,'<',  "$file";

        while(<$pic>) {
            if (/Adobe/) {
                print "$file\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Excitingly, the code seems to be really working and it does the job of filtering out the pictures that have been photoshopped. But problem is many pictures are edited by other utilities. I think I'm kind of stuck there. Do we have some simple but universal method to tell if a digital picture has been edited or not, something like

```
if (!= /the origianl format/) {...}
```

Or do we simply have to add more conditions? like

```
if (/Adobe/|/ACDSee/|/some other picture editors/)
```

Any ideas on this? Or am I oversimplifying due to my miserably limited programming knowledge?

Thanks, as always, for any guidance.

Comment: I don't think so but maybe if you give us the bigger picture we might be able to help otherwise. Why do you want to tell if a photo has been edited?

Comment: @All, so the answer to my question is NO. The reason: like @bdonlan suggested, it's all just a bag of pixels in the end. Well, anyway thanks.

Comment: Just about every decent programming language can handle raw binary image data, even ActionScript in Flash.  None, however, have the magic CSI "enhancement" option.

Comment: @Soviut, I hope my question does not cause controversies or any other unnecessary offences. But I'll edited my post.

Comment: @Hassan Voyeau, thanks for the kind suggestion. Thing is I'm not actually trying to solve any practical problem. I invent problems and try to solve them so that I can improve my Perl knowledge.

Comment: Not all "photoshopped" images are doctored, and not all non-photoshop images are un-doctored. Do you care if someone adjusted the white point, or are you looking for photos where the elements weren't there in the original?

Comment: @brian, looks like people with higher level of programming expertise seem to overcomplicate the situation and on the other hand people like me who are on the beginner level seem to oversimplify things. I was actually just trying to find out thoses pix that have been edited in one way or another, whether minor or major, by some sort of image eidtors. But the fault is all mine. I should not have played with the word "doctored". Perhaps I should have simply said "edited".

Comment: @Mike: It was still a good question. +1 for being curious and wanting to learn more!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet in Perl is probably [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). This gives you access to whatever non-image information is embedded into the image. However, as other people said, it's possible to strip this information out, of course.

Comment: +1 This seems like the best solution to your problem. This would prevent the need of having to hard-code the names of your image editing programs, as this gives you exactly the metadata property's value that stores the program name. This makes it so you don't have to scan the entire file for some string such as "adobe". The other things people said about programs not respecting this metadata property still applies. It's just that for those that do, this is the best solution.

Comment: @eagle, thanks for the explantion. I didn't know that ExifTool is also a Perl module. I thought it to be merely a Windows utility.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to say there is absolutely no way to detect alterations in an image, but the problem is extremely difficult.

The only person I know of who claims to have an answer is [Dr. Neal Krawetz](http://hackerfactor.com), who claims that digitally altered parts of an image will have different compression error rates from the original portions.  He claims that re-saving a JPEG at different quality levels will highlight these differences.

I have not found this to be the case, in my investigations, but perhaps you might have better results.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no functional distinction between a perfectly edited image, and one which was the way it is from the start - it's all just a bag of pixels in the end, after all, and any other metadata you can remove or forge all you want.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the graphics program used to edit the image is not part of the image data itself but of something called meta data - which **may** be stored in the image file but, as others have noted, is neither required (so some programs may not store it, some may allow you an option of not storing it) nor reliable - if you forged an image, you might have forged the meta data as well.

So the answer to your question is "no, there's no way to universally tell if the pic was edited or not, although some image editing software may write its signature into the image file and it'll be left there by carelessness of the editing person.

Comment: Thanks, DVK. Well I know, so unanimous NO to my question. Kind of disappointed. But thanks for the explantion.

Answer (score 3):

If you're inclined to learn more about image processing in Perl, you could take a look at some of the excellent modules CPAN has to offer:

- [Image::Magick](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image::Magick) - read, manipulate and write of a large number of image file formats
- [GD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD/) - create colour drawings using a large number of graphics primitives, and emit the drawings in various formats.
- [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm) - create charts
- [GD::Graph3d](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD-Graph3d/) - create 3D Graphs with GD and GD::Graph

However, there are other utilities available for identifying various image formats. It's more of a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com), but for various unix distros you can use `file` to identify many different types of files, and for MacOSX, [Graphic Converter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/) has never let me down. (It was even able to open the bizarre multi-file X-ray of my cat's shattered pelvis that I got on a disc from the vet.)

Answer (score 1):

How would you know what the original format was?  I'm pretty sure there's no guaranteed way to tell if an image has been modified.

I can just open the file (with my favourite programming language and filesystem API) and just write whatever I want into that file willy-nilly.  As long as I don't screw something up with the file format, you'd never know it happened.

Heck, I could print the image out and then scan it back in; how would you tell it from an original?

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. I guess I was indeed oversimplifying.

Answer (score 1):

As other's have stated, there is no way to know if the image was doctored. I'm guessing what you basically want to know is the difference between a realistic photograph and one that has been enhanced or modified.

There's always the option of running some extremely complex image recognition algorithm that would analyze every pixel in your image and do some very complicated stuff to determine if the image was doctored or not. This solution would probably involve AI which would examine millions of photos that are both doctored and those that are not and learn from them. However, this is more of a theoretical solution and isn't very practical... you would probably only see it in movies. It would be extremely complex to develop and probably take years. And even if you did get something like this to work, it probably still wouldn't be 100% correct all the time. I'm guessing AI technology still isn't at that level and could take a while until it is.

Comment: @eagle, thanks for the comment. It's a little off topic though. But the fault is mine. I invent Perl-related problems and try to solve them the Perl way so that in doing so I can actually improve my Perl knowledge. You dig way deeper than I expected. But thanks for sharing the thoughts. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

A not-commonly-known feature of exiftool allows you to recognize the originating software through an analysis of the JPEG quantization tables (not relying on image metadata).  It recognizes tables written by many applications.  Note that some cameras may use the same quantization tables as some applications, so this isn't a 100% solution, but it is worth looking into.  Here is an example of exiftool run on two images, the first was edited by photoshop.

```
> exiftool -jpegdigest a.jpg b.jpg
======== a.jpg
JPEG Digest                     : Adobe Photoshop, Quality 10
======== b.jpg
JPEG Digest                     : Canon EOS 30D/40D/50D/300D, Normal
    2 image files read
```

This will work even if the metadata has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is existing software out there which uses various techniques (compression artifacting, comparison to signature profiles in a database of cameras, etc.) to analyze the actual image data for evidence of alteration.  If you have access to such software and the software available to you provides an API for external access to these analysis functions, then there's a decent chance that a Perl module exists which will interface with that API and, if no such module exists, it could probably be created rather quickly.

In theory, it would also be possible to implement the image analysis code directly in native Perl, but I'm not aware of anyone having done so and I expect that you'd be better off writing something that low-level and processor-intensive in a fully-compiled language (e.g., C/C++) rather than in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html
is a tool that does the job almost good

If there has been any cloning , there is a variation in the pixel density..or concentration which sometimes shows up.. upon manual inspection 
a Photoshop cloned area will have even pixel density(my meaning is variation of Pixels wrt a scanned image)